# C# math expression parser to work with big numbers

Tags: c#

I work on a `.net` project and need a math expression parser to calculate simple formulas.

I used `mXparser` but it seemed unable to work with big decimal numbers(more than 16 digits) .

For example, the result of formula has to be `2469123211254289589`

but it returns `2.46912321125428E+17` and when I use `decimal.parse` to convert it to decimal it gives me `2469123211254280000`.

Is there another parser to solve this problem?
or
Is there another way to deal with this problem?

Comment: You need to use a "big integer" library.

Comment: thank you @jonathon. could you please name a library for instance?

Comment: You may have to combine a [quad library](https://quadruple.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Quadruple/Quadruple/Quad.cs) with an [expression parser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt573716.aspx) on your own. The parsers I am aware of are using `double` type results.

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy dealing with integers then you should be able to use [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) to carry out these  sorts of operations.

It has no theoretical upper or lower bounds so you shouldn't have a problem (unless you run out of memory to store that number that is).